# ¿Por qué no se pone el fondo negro en este Nav?

Tags: html, css

Con este simple Nav

```html
<nav>
            <div class="logo">BBC</div>
            <div class="login">Sign in</div>
            <div class="items">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>News</li>
                    <li>Sport</li>
                    <li>Weather</li>
                    <li>Shop</li>
                    <li>Reel</li>
                    <li>Travel</li>
                    <li>Capital</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown_item">More</div>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Si hago:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

nav{
    background: black;
    
}
```

No se pone de negro. Sin embargo si le doy a poner el color de los items de blanco por ejemplo si los cambia. O un borde también lo aplica correctamente. ¿Por qué el fondo no?

Comment: lo que pasa es que esta chocando los background.. no sabe cual de los dos aplicar..... si solo aplicas el estilo de nav veras como si aplicas el fondo...

Answer (score 9):

Tu problema **NO** es el nav, este está aplicando sus estilos correctamente y se dibuja de color negro. El problema está dado en que el selector universal aplica a todos y cada uno de los elementos de la página y esta definicion incluye también a los `div`, `ul` y `li` de tu página. Dicho de otra forma el `body` es blanco, el `nav` es negro pero cada uno de los elementos hijos es blanco de nuevo y por lo tanto **el color negro de su elemento contenedor no se ve**.

[image: estilo aplicado]

Los estilos si se aplican y eso lo puedes inspeccionar tu mismo ya que el selector universal (*) [no tiene especificidad](https://specifishity.com/) (0, 0, 0) y el `nav` si (0, 0, 1) y por lo tanto sus estilos (los del `nav`) tienen mayor prioridad.

Este código te ayuda a ver mejor el problema

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

nav {
  background: black;
}

.logo {
  background: inherit;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">BBC</div>
  <div class="login">Sign in</div>
  <div class="items">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>News</li>
      <li>Sport</li>
      <li>Weather</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Reel</li>
      <li>Travel</li>
      <li>Capital</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown_item">More</div>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Fijate que el logo ahora si tiene un color de fondo heredado esta vez de su elemento contenedor.

La solución es simple: no uses el selector universal si es posible; salvo raras excepciones su uso [no es recomendado](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-universal-selector) pues es muy lento. En su lugar **class**ifica o **id**entifica los elementos que quieras estilar y ponle fondo blanco sólo a esos elementos, así el selector universal no te aplicará un estilo por accidente a tus otros elementos.

Comment: Ésta es la respuesta correcta: cuanto más general sea la regla de aplicación, menos prioridad tiene.

Answer (score 4):

Existe un conflicto al inicio de tus css por que declaras con el selector `*` que a todos los elementos de la hoja les aplique un fondo blanco y luego mas abajo indicas que sea negro

```
*{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Esto esta entrando en conflicto con los estilos de mas abajo donde pones que el nav tiene

```
nav{
   background-color: black;
}
```

Si quitas el selector `*` que se usa para aplicar los estilos a todos los elementos de la hoja entonces tendrás el resultado esperado

Prueba envolviendo todo dentro de un div al que le colocarás un id `container` y posterior por css aplicas estilos como en este ejemplo

Yo solo coloque un `hieght` al div contenedor para darle altura y que se note que el color si se aplica de forma independiente al `nav` que tiene el color de fondo negro

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        #container{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          background: red;
          height: 300px;
        }
    
        nav{
          background: black;
          color: white;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">BBC</div>
        <div class="login">Sign in</div>
        <div class="items">
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Sport</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Reel</li>
            <li>Travel</li>
            <li>Capital</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="dropdown_item">More</div>
         <div class="search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
         </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Cierto, fallé en que siempre uso body{} y esta vez usé *{} de verlo tanto. No obstante si es así ahora que lo pienso porque si uso body {background: white;} no hay problemas? Veo entonces que el fallo es por el *, que parece que tiene "autoridad" máxima no es así?

Comment: mi **recomendación** es que no apliques estilos a las etiquetas como body por ejemplo, cuando existe una semántica amplia en la cual tu puedes envolver mas elementos, es decir tienes `section`, `divs`, `nav`, etc  para que evites lo que me comentas; aquí lo que debes es verificar que contenido vas a colocar y checar que etiqueta te funciona mejor para envolverlas y así aplicar estilos de manera mas específica @JavierCake

Answer (score 2):

Prueba colocándole una propiedad `display: block` y quitale la propiedad `background-color: white`al selector `*`

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
nav{
background-color: black !important;
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: También podrías hacerle una CLASE al NAV y esos estilos los pasas a la clase, try it.

Comment: <nav class="back-nav"></nav>

.back-nav{ background-color: black !important; }

Comment: el !important no es necesario ponerlo ya que no hay muchas clases interfiriendo, lo que pasa es que al decirle `*{}` le aplica a todos los elementos del **DOM**, eso es lo que toca corregir, el !important ya es cuando hay muchos estilos aplicados desde diferentes `clases` que ya toca obligarlo

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila gracias por la info (Y)